# How to show a DIV when users reach X pixels from the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the code below to show a banner once users reach the bottom of the screen. Issue is that I noticed that most users don't scroll down till the end. What should I modify to show my div `.banner3` at, let's say, `150px` from the bottom?
Many thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($("body").height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
            $(".banner3").fadeIn()
        } else {
            $(".banner3").css("display","none");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: check the jquery waypoints plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() - 150
```

Easy stuff :)

You could also perhaps rewrite the code a bit nicer. The `scroll` event is fired many times, so you could do some caching of the selector.

```
$(function() {
    var banner = $(".banner3");
    var bodyHeight = $("body").height();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if (bodyHeight <= $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() - 150) {
            banner.fadeIn();
        } else {
            banner.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. Are you sure about the syntax? I tried your 2 suggestions but none of them work...

Comment: @Greg989898 I haven't tested the code, but I can't see anything obvious. Can you elaborate on them *not working*?

Comment: .banner3 doesn't show up anymore... See here: http://goo.gl/22I4kh It's supposed to be on the sky picture. Thanks

Comment: Hi Alex, any idea why this is not working on my site?

Answer (score 1):

edit: forgot to hide the banner again...

http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/RBndE/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(window).scroll(function() {

                if($(this).scrollTop() > $(window).height()-150){
                 $('.banner').fadeIn();
                }else{
                 $('.banner').fadeOut();
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Kasper - but looks like the "result" section of the JSfiddle returns a blank page?

Comment: hi Greg, if you scroll the html (bottom right) pane, a blue banner we be displayed. If you don't see a horizontal scrollbar, you'll need to drag the html pane to a smaller height or change the height value of the body in the css pane. The jsfiddle is working here.